# Optimize the For loop - R

Tags: r

How I can make the following code faster. By now, the whole process for P=1 (i.e. one loop) takes around 15 min. I know the problem should be with `For` loops and I already read several related questions about it but I could not understood how they work.

in following script: P and R are around 1000 and TOLTarget and TOLSource can be maximum 500.

Any help would be grateful.

```
for(i in 1:P)
{
  Source <- MITLinks[i,1]
  Target <- MITLinks[i,2]
  TOLTarget <- sum(!is.na(MITMatrix[Target,]))-1                  # TOLTarget would be the number of concepts for the target course 
  TOLSource <- sum(!is.na(MITMatrix[Source,]))-1
  for(q in 2:TOLSource)                                           # since the first coulmn is the courseID
  {
    DD <- vector(length = R)
    ConceptIDSource <- MITMatrix[Source,q]
    counterq <- 1                                                 # counterq is a pointer to cell of vector DD that keep the corses from another university.
    for(c in 1:R)
    {
      if(CALBinary[c,match(ConceptIDSource,BB)]==1)             # if(CALBinary[c,"ConceptIDSource"]==1)
      {
        DD[counterq] <- c                                     # it is the courseID
        counterq <- counterq+1
      }
    }
    DD <- DD[ DD != 0 ]                                           # DD is a vector that keep all courses from another university hat share the same concepts as source course in the first university (MIT)
    for(j in 2:TOLTarget)                                         # Since the first coulmn is the courseID
    {
      ZZ <- vector(length = R)
      ConceptIDTarget <- MITMatrix[Target,j]
      counter <- 1
      for(v in 1:R)
      {
        if(CALBinary[v,match(ConceptIDTarget,BB)]==1)          #if(CALBinary[v,"ConceptIDTarget"]==1)
        {
          ZZ[counter] <- v                                   # v is courseID
          counter <- counter+1
        }
      }
      ZZ <- ZZ[ ZZ != 0 ]                                        # delete the zero elements from the vector
      Jadval<- expand.grid(Source,Target,ConceptIDSource,ConceptIDTarget,DD,ZZ)
      Total<-rbind(Total,Jadval)                                 # to make all possible pair of the courses for the sorce and the target course
      Total
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Code optimization questions should be asked on CodeReview rather than StackOverflow http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You also should include som background for your code. What is your code trying to do and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of areas where this code can be improved and made faster.  It looks like you are basically writing C-style code, and not taking advantage of built-in vectorized R functions.  Here's one example.  This part of the code:

```
DD <- vector(length = R)
ConceptIDSource <- MITMatrix[Source,q]
counterq <- 1                                                 # counterq is a pointer to cell of vector DD that keep the corses from another university.
for(c in 1:R)
{
  if(CALBinary[c,match(ConceptIDSource,BB)]==1)             # if(CALBinary[c,"ConceptIDSource"]==1)
  {
    DD[counterq] <- c                                     # it is the courseID
    counterq <- counterq+1
  }
}
DD <- DD[ DD != 0 ]
```

can be done like this:

```
ConceptIDSource <- MITMatrix[Source,q]
CalBinaryBB <- CALBinary[,match(ConceptIDSource,BB)]
DD<-which(CalBinaryBB[1:R]==1)
```

In your code, you are calling `match` each time through the loop, which is unnecessary.  And also, since all you are doing is trying to find the indices where `CALBinary[c,match(ConceptIDSource,BB)]==1`, the R function `which` will do this much faster.

It looks like you can do the same thing in the second part of the loop.  And there may be other opportunities for optimization.